# How many ipv6 addresses do I have?

Tags: networking, ipv6, iproute

I have a vps with both ipv4 address and ipv6 address configured. The "ip a" command has the output like:

```
...
    inet yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/24 brd yyy.yyy.yyy.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

The following is the ipv6 related content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6ADDR=xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64
```

So, how many ipv6 addresses do I have, one or 2^64?

Comment: We don't know, you'll have to ask your service provider.

Comment: @ilkkachu so, the command cannot tell me how many ipv6 addresses are available in the system, like ipv4 addresses which I can see clearly?

Comment: how would you see clearly how many IPv4 addresses are available? The problem is that what ever you do inside the system, you can't see any filtering or other configuration done outside it, in the provider's system. And they should have some in place, exactly to stop you from using addresses of other clients. For IPv6, they might of course just give a full /64 block, and if your system is using a SLAAC address, they probably did. But we can't know that for sure.

Comment: I'm sure I have an ipv4 address available by looking at the output of the "ip a" command(see updated output). I think the OS(CentOS) will show all configured ips even it does not know if they are blocked outside the system.

Comment: Why do you think you have multiple IPv6 adresses? `/64` is the default netmask for IPv6, and not an indicator for how many IP adresses your system has.

Comment: @Panki because VPS providers usually assign a block of ipv6 addresses to your vps. I don't know how "ip a" command lists ip addresses. A line for a single ip? But it seems impossible to list a large ipv6 address block in such way.

Comment: How is your network configured, netplan? Did you configure multiple adresses your self, or are you simply getting one by DHCP?

Comment: @Panki please see my updated information. Based on the content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0, I think the ip address is statically configured.

Comment: Theoretically, you have 2^64 addresses, but the last 64 bits of an ipv6 address are the *interface identifier* (derived from the MAC, or randomly generated as per rfc3041), so you cannot actually subnet that 2^64; all the addresses you can use with a /64 prefix should all be in the same segment. So a /64 is not much better than a ipv4 address + nat. Serious ISPs offer /56s to their customers.

Comment: @UncleBilly the advantage is that people outside can connect to the 2^64 ipv6 addresses directly, while they cannot connect to the ipv4 nat addresses.

Comment: Yes. And the disadvantage is that all those devices should all be directly connected (or bridged through) to the router, otherwise they can get no ipv6 connectivity at all. With NAT, you can have a NAT behind another NAT and so on. For instance, if you have a PC connected to a router, and on the PC another system running in a vm like qemu: **a)** with a /64 prefix the vm cannot have any ipv6 connectivity **b)** with NAT if can connect via ipv4 but cannot be reached from outside, and **c)** with a /56 the vm can both connect and be reached from outside via ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is: I have only 1 ipv6 address configured on the system.

Like what @Panki says, "/64 is the default netmask for IPv6, and not an indicator for how many IP adresses your system has."

VPS provider might have assigned more IPs to this VPS but CentOS only configures one ip so apps on the system can use only this ip.

"ip a" shows one ip per line.